# trying to understand the exact different between using `.` and `[]` to get a value from an object

Tags: javascript

trying to understand the exact different between using `.` and `[]` to get a value from an object:

```
const o = {name: "aaa", family: "bbb"};
print(o["name"]);
print(o.name);
```

Are there any cases that one would be preferable over the other one?

Comment: What if the name of the property wasn't a valid identifier? What if it was coming in dynamically as a string value?

Comment: @jonrsharpe  can you explaine more please?

Comment: What if you started with `{ 'hello world': 3 }`. How do you get `3`? What if you have `const a = 'hello world'`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe oh i see, so in case that it's dynamically coming from somewhere we use [], right?

Comment: The benefit of the first example is that you can do `var propertyName = 'name'; print (o[propertyName]);` If you don't know until runtime which property you want to read, that's good. If you do know at runtime then the second way is simpler and safer.

Comment: Why the downvotes? I'm not clear how this "Doesn't show research effort, is unclear or not helpful"?

Comment: @Liam thanks for that

Comment: In a nutshell: `.` must use a *valid identifier*, `[]` takes any *expression*. `.` is shorter, but more limited.

Comment: There are some key differences. For example, bracket notation can be used with variables while dot cannot.

    const selector = "name"
    const o = {name: "aaa", family: "bbb"};
    console.log(o[selector]) --selects name
    console.log(o.selector) --fails

Comment: Thank all, can one please post it as an answer?